# Undefined Method Create for AR Model Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in my Rails application:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :higher_education
  attr_accessible :higher_education_id
end

class HigherEducation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end
```

First I execute the following command:

```
he = HigherEducation.create()

 (0.0ms)  begin transaction                                                                                                                    
  SQL (56.4ms)  INSERT INTO "higher_education" ("created_at", "text", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 27 Oct 2015 04:22:14 UTC +00:0│
0], ["text", "baz"], ["updated_at", Tue, 27 Oct 2015 04:22:14 UTC +00:00]]                                                                       │
   (10.3ms)  commit transaction                                                                                                                 
=> #<HigherEducation id: 3, text: "baz", created_at: "2015-10-27 04:22:14", updated_at: "2015-10-27 04:22:14">
```

Next, I execute another command and get an error:

```
he.students.create()
=> nil
```

I get back `NoMethodError: undefined method create for nil:NilClass`.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you edit your question to do the following: Open a Rails console session and walk through those exact steps? I suspect there's something else going on between those two steps.

Comment: More specifically, are you _sure_ that `he` is getting created? Or is it failing creation based on validation errors?

Comment: And then right after that... he.students.create()? Can you show that whole transaction as well?

Comment: Hmm. That's weird. Is it possible that you have another `students` method defined in the Higher Education class that's overriding the `students` association?

Comment: try `he.reload` and then `he.students` ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `attr_accessible :higher_education_id`.

Rails reads the database schema (not `schema.rb` but the actual tables) at startup and creates setters and getters for the columns in your database.

lets say your table looks like this:

```
students
  - id [Int, Index, primary key]
  - email [Varchar]
  - higher_education_id [Int, Index, Foreign Key]
```

Your Student instances will already respond to `.email`,`.email=`, `.higher_education_id`, `.higher_education_id=` ...

Additionally when you set up a relationship in your model Rails will overwrite these setters and getters so that they setup the related object as well.

The only time you should use `attr_accessible` in ActiveRecord models is when you want to use a "virtual attribute" that is not backed by a database column.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are getting an unexpected behavior because your students table does not actually have a `higher_education_id` column. `attr_accessible` masks the error and instead the relation is just saved into nothing.